# how to download dse.jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to use DataStax Enterprise 4.6 to write a Spark application in Java and run
it in DSE's Spark analytics mode.

The code for creating a Spark context using `DSEConfHelper`:

```
SparkConf conf = DseSparkConfHelper.enrichSparkConf(new SparkConf())
            .setAppName( "My application");
```

To use `DSEConfHelper` we need to import `com.datastax.bdp.spark.DseSparkConfHelper`
which is located in `dse.jar`.

In my `pom.xml` I have included the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax</groupId>
    <artifactId>bdp</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But Maven cannot download `dse.jar`.

Please help me.

The reference for code  for creating a Spark context is taken from:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: DseSparkConfHelper cannot be resolved

Comment: I mean the Maven error, you said it's not downloading the dependency.

Comment: the POM for com.datastax:bdp:jar:4.6.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

Comment: Run maven with debug options `mvn install -e -X` and see what is the error stacktrace

Comment: Where did you find this <artifactId>bdp</artifactId> ? on the docs you mention it is: `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @MDev you should update your question with the error instead of posting it as a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: This has been entirely superceded by the com.datastax.dse.dse-spark-dependencies artifact. Add it to your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse-spark-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${dse.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
<dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>DataStax-Repo</id>
    <url>https://repo.datastax.com/public-repos/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

See https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples for Maven, SBT, and Gradle example projects.

**Original, outdated answer**:

You have to manually install `dse.jar` as of right now. There are two ways of doing this.

**Option 1**
Install the JAR file using `mvn install`:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-dse.jar> -DgroupId=com.datastax -DartficactId=bdp -Dversion=4.6.0
```

**Option 2**
Manually copy `dse.jar` from your install location to `${project.basedir}/lib/`. Then modify your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax</groupId>
  <artifactId>bdp</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/dse.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I don't really know why you're calling the artifact "bdp", but for these purposes it doesn't matter, and I just used it as well.

Comment: Solid post Ian, by the way, dse.jar is in the /lib folder in the dse tarball or package install. This may be what M dev is looking for.

Comment: How this answer got any points? The question is "How to downloaddse.jar", the answer only explain how to install an already downloaded dse.jar.

Comment: No, the question was how to download dse.jar as a Maven dependency.

Comment: While this answer explains how to install the downloaded jar, this does not clearly explain, from where the actual jar can be downloaded.

Comment: You need to download the tarball from the link below and extract that to find the jar in lib folder: https://academy.datastax.com/all-downloads?field_download_driver_category_tid=910

Comment: I edited my answer to describe how to use the published Maven artifacts to get the correct JARs.

Answer (score 0):

dse.jar is part of DSE installation. If you are working in windows environment, you can find it here [dse.jar](https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-previous-versions#dl-community-drivers)

register,download and extact to find the jar in lib folder. The use the above answer to add it in your maven project.