# Can I use regular Spark Core application library to talk to DSE Spark?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

A couple of days ago we upgraded from DSE 4.6 to DSE 4.7. We're running Spark jobs from Java so I've upgraded `spark-core_2.10` Maven dependency from `0.9.1` to `1.2.2` to support the newer Spark 1.2.2 that DSE bundles with. However, when I'm now submitting jobs to master it logs

```
ERROR [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] 2015-11-17 17:50:42,442  Slf4jLogger.scala:66 - org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7674242335164700840, local class serialVersionUID = 2812534333379744973
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7674242335164700840, local class serialVersionUID = 2812534333379744973
[...]
```

(see full exception here: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/371d00701ff7f2021d7d)

Digging further into this, it turns out that DSE ships with `spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar` which is

1. not AFAIK published as a Maven artefact on the Interwebz.
2. not tagged as released in GIT repository in https://github.com/apache/spark.
3. shipping with a different `serialVersionUID` of `org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription` than `spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.jar` (`1.2.2`, that is). I have verified this using `serialver`.

**Question:** The [Datastax Java Spark documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html) never mentions anything about importing Spark Core. **Should I be able to use the standard Spark Java Maven artifact with DSE?**

Additionals:

- I have added `dse.jar` to the classpath and that's not the issue.
- The [Datastax Java Spark documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html) doesn't state which Spark Code version to use. See related [What do I need to import to make `SparkConf` resolvable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33781890/260805).
- The `ApplicationDescription` class doesn't fixate its `serialVersionUID`. Decompiling the `ApplicationDescription.class` for `1.2.2` and `1.2.2.2`, it looks like they both use the same number of fields but have different methods, which leads to `serialVersionUID` being generated differently. One potential upstream DSE fix would be to simply fixate the `serialVersionUID` to `7674242335164700840`.
- Somewhat related; To make things even more complicated we have a repackaged `spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.jar` to shadow a package that broke our application. However, we could probably use the [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) for this even if we don't have source code for `1.2.2.2`.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020757/how-to-download-dse-jar

Comment: Thanks @phact. Unfortunately, that doesn't help me. I have `dse.jar` in the classpath (as also mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/q/33781890/260805).

Comment: Okay check out this example https://github.com/rssvihla/spark_commons/tree/master/examples/maven_example

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I find it hard to see why that would work, too: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/6dff9729079d04165e6f

Comment: @phact: Sorry, I forgot to ask: Do you have any other ideas? AFAIK I have three possible ways to go: 1) I manually bundle the `spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar` that DSE ships with, 2) Datastax publishes a Maven package for `spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar` (and document that it must be used) or 2) DSE patches the `serialVersionUID` upstream.

Comment: Allright, 1) & 2) are out of the question. It throws a NoClassDefFoundError. See https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/acd9f60f6aad2371e9d0. Unless, I start bundling some other JAR from the DSE distribution.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33781890/260805